# Having Java call an Applescript file with arguments

Tags: java, arguments, applescript

I have a Java program that calls an Applescript file to run, and returns information back to Java. However, I need to also pass some arguments *to* the Applescript file. The relevant portion of the Java file:

```
public static void scriptRunner(String[] args) {
    
    // Connect to the database.
    ConnectionManager.getInstance().setDBType(DBType.MYSQL);

    // Prepare the AppleScript file to be executed.
    String homeFolder = System.getenv("HOME");
    File scriptFile = new File(homeFolder + "/Documents/Output--Test.applescript");
    InputStream scriptStream = null;
    try {
        scriptStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(scriptFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not find the Output AppleScript file.  Please notify Chris McGee", "File not found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ConnectionManager.getInstance().close();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(scriptStream));

    // These two lines prepare the scripting engine, ready to run the script.
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");

    // Add the parameters to the engine so they will be passed to the script.
    engine.put("javaOrderNum", args[0]);
    engine.put("javaShipDate", args[1]);
    engine.put("javaInitials", args[2]);
    engine.put("javaOverruns", args[3]);
    
    // Run the script and evaluate the result.
    log.trace("Run the script and evaluate the result.");
    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = engine.eval(bufferedReader); // Run the script and place the result into an abstract object.
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Either an error occurred with the Output script or the user cancelled it.", "Script error / cancel", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        ConnectionManager.getInstance().close();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    log.debug(result); // Check that we received the correct information back from the script.
    log.debug("");
.
.
.
```

Sadly, the `engine.put` lines, as suggested from a forum I read during my searches to get this problem solved, don't seem to work. The AppleScript file:

```
-- Get variables passed in
set jOrderNum to item 1 of arguments
set jShipDate to item 2 of arguments
set jInitials to item 3 of arguments
set jOverruns to item 4 of arguments

-- Set the correct folder variable
if (folderExists(POSIX path of "/Volumes/Users/Scripts/")) then
    set server_prefix to "/Volumes/Users/Scripts/"
else if (folderExists(POSIX path of "/centralserver/Users/Scripts/")) then
    set server_prefix to "/centralserver/Users/Scripts/"
else
    display alert "Please connect to the central server, then try again.
If you have already done so, please let Chris McGee know."
end if

with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds
    tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
        
        set myJavaScript to server_prefix & "sky-artdept/Test/Output.jsx"
        set myResult to do script myJavaScript with arguments {jOrderNum, jShipDate, jInitials, jOverruns} language javascript
        return myResult
        
    end tell
end timeout

on folderExists(posixPath)
    return ((do shell script "if test -e " & quoted form of posixPath & "; then
        echo 1;
        else
        echo 0;
        fi") as integer) as boolean
end folderExists
```

I am given an error that the variable `arguments` is not defined. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the javascript running the applescript. But, you applescript code is missing a declaration. You're asking for "item 1 of arguments" but you never define the variable arguments.
When the script is not inside any handler, it is implicit that it is inside a run() handler. And, since you're needing to pass arguments on run, you should try wrapping your script, minus the on folderExists() handler, inside a run handler that includes the arguments declaration.

```
on run(arguments)

    -- Get variables passed in
set jOrderNum to item 1 of arguments
set jShipDate to item 2 of arguments
…
end timeout
end run
on folderExists(posixPath)
…
end folderExists
```